# Installation failed for API

Tags: application-development, development, c

I'm developing an app for sending OSC messages working through the outlet port 4444 and I am using a C API call Liblo.

Project page: http://liblo.sourceforge.net

Normal install it by running the command: ./Configure, make and sudo make install but when executing a file API appears the following error message:

`example_client.c gcc-llo`
`example_client.c: 21:10: fatal error: 'lo / lo.h' file not found`
`# include <lo/lo.h>`
I will check the correctness of the same and see that the folder "lo" folder (API) is not discharged in the lib directory, but in the include. Then I export this same folder to the lib directory and the error persists.

What can be this error?

Answer (score 1):

You must install [`liblo-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=lo%2Flo.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any):

```
sudo apt-get install liblo-dev
```